# GLSL - Rewriting shaders from #330 to #130

Tags: opengl, glsl

I recently created a game ([LD21](http://www.ludumdare.com/compo/ludum-dare-21/?action=preview&uid=2443)) that uses a geometry shader to convert points into textured triangles/culling. Since I was under the impression that the support for #330 was widespread I only wrote #330 shaders, but it seems that a lot of not so old hardware only support #130 (according to GLView)

Now, since I'm only familiar with the #330 core functionality I am having trouble rewriting my shaders to #130. The fragment shader was quite trivial to rewrite, but I've only managed to get my vertex and geometry shader down to #150.

So, is it possible to rewrite the shaders, or would it require a lot of changes in my rendering engine?

## Geometry shader

```
#version 150
layout(points) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 4) out;
uniform mat4 oMatrix;
in VertexData
{
    vec4 position;
    vec4 texcoord;
    vec4 size;
} vert;

out vec2 gTexCoord;

void main()
{
    if(vert.position.x>-4f && vert.position.x<4f && vert.position.y>-2f && vert.position.y<2f)
    {
        gTexCoord=vec2(vert.texcoord.z,vert.texcoord.y);
        gl_Position = vert.position + vec4(vert.size.x,vert.size.y,0,0);
        EmitVertex();

        gTexCoord=vec2(vert.texcoord.x,vert.texcoord.y);
        gl_Position = vert.position + vec4(0.0,vert.size.y,0,0);
        EmitVertex();
    
        gTexCoord=vec2(vert.texcoord.z,vert.texcoord.w);
        gl_Position = vert.position + vec4(vert.size.x,0.0,0,0);
        EmitVertex();

        gTexCoord=vec2(vert.texcoord.x,vert.texcoord.w);
        gl_Position = vert.position;
        EmitVertex();

        EndPrimitive();
    }
}
```

## Vertex shader

```
#version 150
#extension GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location : enable

layout (location = 0) in vec2 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 textureCoord;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 size;
uniform mat4 oMatrix;
uniform vec2 offset;
out VertexData
{
    vec4 position;
    vec4 texcoord;
    vec4 size;
} outData;

void main()
{
    outData.position = oMatrix * vec4(position.x+offset.x,position.y+offset.y,0,1);
    outData.texcoord = textureCoord;
    outData.size = oMatrix * vec4(size.x,size.y,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to inform yourself about the accept and up-vote features.

Comment: "Don't forget to inform yourself about the accept and up-vote features." Read : "Accept my Answer."

Comment: @Jonathan Wasn't meant that way. It's not rude to not accept if the answer was not of help. Actually the OP has maybe accepted my answer too fast (sorry for that). But I often (even in my still short SO-life) I see one-time visitors ask a question and then completely forget about it (maybe they solved it 3 minutes later themselves or they mistook the site as a forum). But the reputation system is the driving force of this feedback oriented Q&A site. It wasn't meant to immediately accept my answer without thought, but as written, to be aware of the accept feature (as many newbies aren't).

Comment: @Jonathan And by the way, I have already written those reminders in first questions not answered by me. But you're right in that it is a bit self-interrested here.

Comment: @kmm No, if intended with good reason. But ignoring or just not knowing the workings of this feedback-oriented Q&A-site is a problem for me. Neither was this comment a command to accept, but to be aware of the feature with its implications (that the answer has to be helpful or the most helpful from a bunch of possibly multiple helpful answers).

Comment: @Christian Rau This does indeed sometimes happen though it's probably best to give people the benefit of the doubt. If you do want to post a comment, "Welcome, please read the site rules" would be more appropriate IMO :) Oh and +1 for your answer ;)

Comment: @Jonathan Ok sorry, perhaps it was a bit too direct from me. I've learned my lesson. And thanks for your suggestion (and the up-vote).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you won't be able to use `struct`s for varying data (changed by 1.50), but you still can use `in` and `out` instead of `attribute` and `varying`. Additionally you have to write into the builtin variable `gl_Position` in the vertex shader (changed by 1.40). So in your vertex shader substitute the declaration of `outData` with something similar to

```
out vec4 texcoord;
out vec4 vSize;       //size already used
```

and use `gl_Position` instead of `outData.position`.

I'm not sure if the ARB_explicit_attrib_location extension is already core, so maybe you have to add

```
#extension ARB_explicit_attrib_location : require
```

to use the `layout` syntax or just set the attribute locations in the application by calling `glBindAttribLocation` before linking the shader, if this extension is not supprted.

In the geometry shader change the decralation of vert to something like

```
in vec4 texcoord[];      //names have to match vertex shader, of course
in vec4 vSize[];
```

Although you only get a single input (as you're using points), they still have to be arrays, I think (although always index with `[0]`, when used). Change the use of `vert.position` to `gl_PositionIn[0]`.

Next, I think the `layout` syntax for the geometry shader has been introduced in 1.50, so you might have to set the geometry shader layout in the application by means of `glProgramParameteri`.

I have to admit, that I have not much practical experience with geometry shaders or the modern syntax, as I still sit on 2.1 hardware, but all these changes can be deduced by looking into the respective [specifications](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/). Just look at the shader info logs if compilation (or linking) fails to gain some hints about what could be wrong.

The missing of the `layout` syntax in both the vertex and the geometry shader are the only things that might require some small additions to your application code, but I'm not completely sure if they are really unsupprted, so try them last.

Also, feel free to update your question if I missed anything and the shaders still don't work, maybe this time with some error messages from the GLSL compiler.

Comment: Thanks! Got it down to #140, but #130 is within my reach :)

Comment: @nilstatic So what have you changed and what still doesn't work. Maybe you can edit your question to include the new 1.40 shaders. If you already got 1.40, maybe you just have to change the use of your custom `position` varying`to `gl_Position`.